# Rich:tab action problem

Tags: jsf-2

In my sample one form of JSF application that contains tab panel and inside that having 3 tabs, each tab having different components like(input Text , output Text,etc), and parent page of this tab panel having common save method.

**Problem is**: when i  was doing some thing (entering value in input text,etc) in  any  one tab (e.g 3rd tab ) and after clicking save button , **it defaults open to the  first tab  after saving, but I need to remain in the same tab.**

How can i do that??

Will you you help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for that case to use a4j:jsFunction for example

Then on each tab we use onleave="clean()" which will call the function from backing bean

like

Hope That help (*_*)